# Chosen plugin don't sending selected data on php

Tags: php, jquery-chosen

I have simple select, He was work before install chosen plugin

```
<select id="product_brands" class="chosen-select form-control" multiple data-placeholder="Select brands">
@foreach($brands as $brand)
    <option name="product[brands][]" value="{{$brand->brand_id}}"> {{$brand->brand_name}} </option>
@endforeach
```

Set chosen

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen({width: "100%"});
```

And when I do print_r in my php script I get nothing from selected data

```
array:2 ["main" => array:2 ["name" => "test", "count" => "0" ] "contacts" => "1196656" ]
```

There should have been a list product[brands] (

Comment: Which means your array is empty. Please check this

Comment: @RonnieOosting I showed you the result of the received data. It does not have the required data selected. This is an array $_POST

Comment: Could $brands  be empty?

Comment: @RonnieOosting Well, of course not ( look on next [screen](http://prntscr.com/kks26y)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what the problem is. I did not correctly indicate the type of array in the form.
Need make then:
1. Add in select tag attribute - **multiple="multiple"**
2. Add in select tag attribute - **name="product[brands][]"**

```
<select id="product_brands" class="chosen-select form-control" multiple="multiple" name="product[brands][]" data-placeholder="Select brands">
```

And everything will work as it should

Comment: Awesome alex! Great job :-)